# How to create an update form with Apollo client in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I like to edit a list of contacts I fetched from my GraphQL api with Apollo client. I see a lot of examples for add new items via mutations but I cannot find any example of updating existing items. Normally I would create a state object and make the input fields modify the properties of the state object but I'm not sure how I can modify the data I have fetched. How do I keep the view state updated?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

class EditContact extends Component {
  _update() {
    // Mutation call
  }

  render() {
    if(this.props.contactQuery && this.props.contactQuery.loading) {
      return <div>Loading</div>
    }
    if(this.props.contactQuery && this.props.contactQuery.error) {
      return <div>Error</div>
    }
    const contact = this.props.contactQuery.contact;

    return(
      <div className="contact">
        <input type="text" defaultValue={contact.firstName} onChange={??} />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" onClick={this._update}>
      </div>)
  }
}

const CONTACT_QUERY = gql`
  query contactQuery($id: Int!) {
    contact(id: $id) {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
  `

export default graphql(CONTACT_QUERY, {
  name: 'contactQuery',
  options: ownProps => ({ variables: { id: ownProps.match.params.id } })
})(EditContact);
```

I know how to create and use the mutation itself but how do I keep track of the form changes and how do I set the initial data in the form fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a Controlled input, I learned about them here: https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/

Comment: That's what I meant with what I would normally do. But the data is fetched asynchronously and this.props.contactQuery.contact is not available in the constructor right away. So how do I set the initial data when it is loaded?

Comment: i normally initialize the state with empty strings and then in componentWillReceiveProps have a case to see when contact is available and call an initialize function with the contact that updates the state with correct values.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is so simple. I check if this.props.contactQuery and this.props.contactQuery.contact is set in componentWillReceiveProps and then set the state like you suggest. Thanks brub.